# Separar números Pares, Ímpares e valores Iguais em Matriz pelo VBA (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

como fazer uma matriz 10x10, separar pares e impares e iguais sem usar Mod ?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AGORA COM O CÓDIGO PRONTO E TESTADO!**

A **solução apresentada no código abaixo** trata cada elemento da matriz por vez para identificar os números **pares** e **ímpares** nela contidos. Na sequência, dentro da ordem de análise por elemento da matriz, há também a verificação de quantos valores são **iguais** (considerando a quantidade total que cada número repetido está na matriz) e quantos números são **Repetidos** (caso queira distinguir "iguais" de "repetidos" como eu fiz, senão o seu "iguais" trata-se do meu "repetidos"):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    SepararValores

End Sub

Private Sub SepararValores()

    Dim Matriz(10, 10), Pares(100), Impares(100), Iguais(100) As String

    Dim Qtde_Pares, Qtde_Impares, Qtde_Iguais, _
        MenorNumeroInteiro, MaiorNumeroInteiro, _
        NumeroDeLinhas, NumeroDeColunas, _
        i, j, s, t, k, Aux_IndiceIguais As Integer

    Dim Aux_String, Linha As String

    Dim OcorrenciaDeNumerosIguais As Boolean

    Aux_String = ""

    NumeroDeLinhas = 10 'A matriz está dimensionada para ser no máximo 10 x 10, mas pode alterar o dimensionamento se precisar.
    NumeroDeColunas = 10

    MenorNumeroInteiro = 1
    MaiorNumeroInteiro = 99

    Aux_String = " Matriz " & NumeroDeLinhas & " x " & NumeroDeColunas

    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print Aux_String
    Debug.Print " " & Left("--------------------", Len(Aux_String) - 1)
    Debug.Print ""

    Linha = ""

    Randomize

    'Preenche a matriz
    For i = 1 To NumeroDeLinhas

        For j = 1 To NumeroDeColunas

            Matriz(i, j) = CStr(Int((MaiorNumeroInteiro - MenorNumeroInteiro + 1) * Rnd()) + MenorNumeroInteiro)

            If Len(CStr(Matriz(i, j))) < 2 Then Matriz(i, j) = "0" & Matriz(i, j)

            Linha = Linha & " " & Matriz(i, j)

        Next j

        Debug.Print Linha

        Debug.Print ""

        Linha = ""

    Next i

    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print " Solução"
    Debug.Print " -------"
    Debug.Print ""

    Qtde_Pares = 0
    Qtde_Impares = 0
    Qtde_Iguais = 0

    Aux_IndiceIguais = 0 'Indice para registro dos números Iguais

    'Trata cada elemento da matriz por vez, para achar os
    'Pares, Ímpares e os Iguais
    For i = 1 To NumeroDeLinhas

        For j = 1 To NumeroDeColunas

            If Int(Matriz(i, j) / 2) - Matriz(i, j) / 2 = 0 Then
              'Se é Par

               Qtde_Pares = Qtde_Pares + 1

               Pares(Qtde_Pares) = Matriz(i, j)

            Else
              'Se é Ímpar

               Qtde_Impares = Qtde_Impares + 1

               Impares(Qtde_Impares) = Matriz(i, j)

            End If

            'Calcula a quantidade de valores iguais na matriz
            'Sem refazer para um mesmo valor

            OcorrenciaDeNumerosIguais = False

            For s = 1 To NumeroDeLinhas

                For t = 1 To NumeroDeColunas

                    'Faz se encontrou um valor igual, mas que
                    '"i" e "j" não sejam iguais a "s" e "t" simultaneamente
                    If Matriz(s, t) = Matriz(i, j) And (s <> i Or t <> j) Then

                        'Faz se é um valor não encontrado anteriormente
                        If s > i Or (s = i And t > j) Then

                            Qtde_Iguais = Qtde_Iguais + 1

                            If Not OcorrenciaDeNumerosIguais Then

                                OcorrenciaDeNumerosIguais = True

                                Qtde_Iguais = Qtde_Iguais + 1
                                'Soma mais um pois deve considerar o
                                'próprio número procurado

                                'Fica com a quantidade de números repetidos
                                Aux_IndiceIguais = Aux_IndiceIguais + 1

                                Iguais(Aux_IndiceIguais) = Matriz(i, j)

                            End If

                        Else

                           'Se é um valor já considerado anteriormente,
                           'deve ignorá-lo e já passar a pegar o próximo,
                           'senão duplicaria várias vezes este resultado,
                           'pois já pegou todos da primeira vez

                           GoTo Sair_deste_loop

                        End If

                    End If

                Next t

            Next s

        Sair_deste_loop:

        Next j

    Next i

    'Parte da impressão de daodos
    'Use a Janela de Verificação Imediata do VBA
    'Para ver a matriz e os respectivos resultados

    Linha = ""

    For i = 1 To Qtde_Pares

        Linha = Linha & " " & Pares(i)

    Next i

    Debug.Print " " & Qtde_Pares & " números Pares:" & Linha
    Debug.Print ""

    Linha = ""

    For i = 1 To Qtde_Impares

        Linha = Linha & " " & Impares(i)

    Next i

    Debug.Print " " & Qtde_Impares & " números Ímpares:" & Linha
    Debug.Print ""

    Linha = ""

    For i = 1 To Aux_IndiceIguais

        Linha = Linha & " " & Iguais(i)

    Next i

    Debug.Print " " & Qtde_Iguais & " números Iguais:" & Linha
    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print " " & Aux_IndiceIguais & " números Repetidos."
    Debug.Print ""

    Beep

End Sub
```

Comment: Luana, PRONTO! Aqui está o código COMPLETO e TESTADO!

Comment: leo, infelizmente não estou conseguindo fazer, mas muito obrigada pela ajuda :)

Comment: Oi Luana, da forma que fiz basta você copiar e colar na parte do código de um formulário novo, abra a Janela de Verificação Imediata do VBA e execute, o formulário aparecerá sem nada (sem objetos), mas na janela de verificação é mostrada a matriz e todas as soluções. Faça isso que ficou muito legal, se tiver dificuldade me diga quais para te ajudar. Depois, por favor, marque a resposta. Não deixe de tentar, todos aqui estamos na comunidade para aprender e compartilhar conhecimento.

Comment: Assim deu certo agora, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Valeu! Bons estudos.

Comment: Tenho  uma dúvida no caso para formulário parece na planilha do excel  tinha que se outro código usando  o cells  ?

Comment: Oi Luana, não entendi sua pergunta, mas se for para colocar os resultados na planilha, você pode usar o Cells(linha,coluna) = Valor, ou o Range("B3").Value  = Valor, ou se a célula tiver nome: Range("Nome").Value = Valor. Você já pegou o esquema daqui? Pode votar também se não votou (setas), e caso tenha mais dúvidas o ideal é criar outra pergunta mostrando parte de seu código onde está tendo dificuldade e descrever sua dificuldade, pois é ruim estender as conversas aqui pelos comentários, elas não ajudam aos demais interessados.

Comment: Leo, nada contra vc ter feito todo o trabalho pra AP (opção sua). Mas, por que você fez usando `UserForm`? As vezes ela só queria uma função pra usar na planilha. Acho que vc tem andado estudando criação de formulários no Excel, e dai está usando em tudo o que é lugar mesmo sem ser necessário, não? rs Cuidado, senão vc corre o risco de se tornar o exemplo proverbial (“Para quem só sabe usar martelo, todo problema é um prego.”) :)

Comment: Oi Luiz, ok, mas acho que você não observou que ela estava fazendo isso em um módulo!!! Se olhar o histórico dela, ela postou três vezes a mesma questão (sinalizei como duplicadas, veja como o moderador indicou nos comentários e não nos títulos). Como percebi que ela não estava conseguindo fazer, ajudei de forma sofisticada, eu sei... É isso amigo, o que estou programando em VBA não é nada "usual", por isso preciso de apoio nas questões que tenho feito, e te agradeço muito pelo apoio que tem me dado, o que estou fazendo está ficando muito bom, em breve apresentarei o projeto para terceiros.